# Wrap div inside columns?

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

My website layout has 3 columns:
[image]

I need insert div inside 2 columns, so the result should be:[image]

```css
div { column-count:3; column-gap:3rem }
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Column text</p>
  <p>...</p>
</div>
```

I have tried many methods and no one works. Can you help me?

Comment: What does your HTML look like? Does it need to fit a certain structure?

Comment: @symlink added HTML to the question. Very simple structure, but simplicity makes hard...

Comment: Did you try `float: right` on the div you want to insert?

Comment: Yes, I tried. Then DIV goes to right side and layout looks like 4 columns.

Comment: Did you try wrapping the two right hand columns in a div, and then making a child div, in the parent div, that spans the whole width of the parent div?

Answer (score 1):

Use css grid. Here is an example.

```css
div[id="grid"] {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(10, 30px);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 100px);
}

div[id="grid"] > div {
  background-color: pink;
  border: 2px solid cyan;
}

div[id="more-space"]{
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
}
```

```html
 <div id="grid">
    <div>grid item</div>
    <div>grid item</div>
    <div>grid item</div>
    <div id="more-space" >use more space</div>
    <div>grid item</div>
    <div>grid item</div>
    <div>grid item</div>
    <div>grid item</div>
    <div>grid item</div>
    <div>grid item</div>
    <div>grid item</div>
    <div>grid item</div>
    <div>grid item</div>
    <div>grid item</div>
    <div>grid item</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking about GRID, but don't know how to show only 1 grid per row on mobile.

Comment: 1 grid per row... what?

Comment: @PatMan10 He means change `grid-template-columns` to `100%`